# How do I make a terminal alias that edits root owned files in a GUI text editor?

Tags: terminal, text-editor, alias, root

How can I quickly edit root owned files like /etc/hosts and /etc/apache2/httpd.conf in a text editor such as TextEdit which would let me do modern text editor operations, without actually running the editor in sudo -b mode first, or without using nano, vim and other terminal based editors?

Ever since Lion came out, doing

```
$sudo open -e /etc/hosts
```

no longer works - the file remains locked when TextEdit opens it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo` and `open` provide all the functionality already for editing files of other users so you can just run

```
SUDO_EDITOR="open -FWne" sudo -e /etc/hosts
```

to edit `/etc/hosts`. Make sure to **quit** Textedit at the end (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>) because otherwise `sudo` won't notice that you're done with editing.

To make life easier add the following to your `.bashrc` (or `.alias` if you have it)

```
alias sudoedit='SUDO_EDITOR="open -FWne" sudo -e'
```

Comment: Hmm. Doesn't work for me. This command opens up a sort of temporary clone of hosts in the form of hosts.5o3nev8 and edits that one. If I save it and re-run the command, it opens the same file (changes are there) but a different suffix is at the end. However, no matter what I do via SUDO_EDITOR, if I go and look at the real /etc/hosts, it stays the same - like it was before the first SUDO_EDITOR command.

Comment: It opens a temporary file but it should get copied back to the original **after you quit Textedit** (at least it does for me), see http://d.pr/i/sMN2

Comment: You are correct. It is worth noting that the TextEditor instance needs to be killed completely in order to overwrite the original - if it stays on but the editing window is closed, the overwrite does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step solution:

1. Download the free TextWrangler app ( http://www.barebones.com/products/TextWrangler/ )
2. Create a .profile file in your home folder if it does not exist

   ```
   $ touch ~/.profile
   $ open -e ~/.profile
   ```
3. Edit the file and give it the following aliases, along with any others you may wish to add:

   ```
   alias edit_hosts='sudo open -a /Applications/TextWrangler.app/Contents/MacOS/TextWrangler /etc/hosts'
   alias edit_vhosts='sudo open -a /Applications/TextWrangler.app/Contents/MacOS/TextWrangler /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf'
   alias edit_httpd='sudo open -a /Applications/TextWrangler.app/Contents/MacOS/TextWrangler /etc/apache2/httpd.conf'
   alias edit_alias='open -a /Applications/TextWrangler.app/Contents/MacOS/TextWrangler ~/.profile'

   alias reload_alias='. ~/.profile'
   ```
4. Save the file and run:

   ```
   $ reload_alias
   ```

Now when you run edit_hosts or the other edit_* aliases, the TextWrangler app should open the hosts file. It will still be locked, but this application can unlock it once you start editing, it will prompt you. You now have a one-line command to edit the root owned files of your choice.

You can also alias just the first part of the path:

```
alias edit='sudo open -a /Applications/TextWrangler.app/Contents/MacOS/TextWrangler'
```

which will let you execute commands such as

```
$ edit /etc/hosts
```

and still achieve the same results.

Edit: other answer looks to be a better solution as it does not require the download and installation of another application.

Comment: For completeness sake, the `reload_alias` command won't work unless you source the profile once with `. ~/.profile`